# ASP NET Core - Use OData with mongoDB - Fails serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to integrate OData in an ASP NET Core app.
The particularity is I have a Mongo DB and I use Mongo DB driver to set my request as`IQueryable` ; I have simplified the code below and it seems the serializer mongo fails

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ODataQueryOptions<Policy> queryOptions)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
    var collection = client.GetDatabase("policy-server").GetCollection<Policy>("policy");
    var policies = collection.AsQueryable();
    var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(policies);
    var s = query.ToString(); // error in toString()
    return Ok(s); 
}
```

I have the followed error calling his URL [https://localhost:44355/api/policies?$select=isEnabled][1]

> ArgumentException: Value type of serializer is Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.PropertyContainer+NamedProperty`1[[System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] and does not match member type Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.PropertyContainer. (Parameter 'serializer')
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonMemberMap.SetSerializer(IBsonSerializer serializer) in BsonMemberMap.cs, line 480

Can someone has already mixed OData and MongoDB Driver ?

Thx

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem? Facing the exact same here :(

Comment: Forget it. I rolled my own OData parser, and generated my expressions in a non-fucked up way (unlike .net) and it works beautifully ;)

Comment: can you check this query without OData? This looks like a pretty trivial one, if it causes this issue without odata, I can help with this

Comment: @dododo the issue appears when using select, not with orderby or filter

Comment: are u using IIF statements?

Comment: @GeraldHughes, I see it, this is why I think it's possible to try this query in console app (or something), if it's reproducible there, I can help with this. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with ODATA itself

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu not using IIF statement

Comment: @dododo i don't think it can be reproduced in console, because of the [EnableQuery] decoration. but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`query` is of type `IQueryable`

See example

```
public PageResult<Product> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> options)
{
ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings()
{
    PageSize = 5
};

IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(_products.AsQueryable(), settings);

return new PageResult<Product>(
    results as IEnumerable<Product>, 
    Request.GetNextPageLink(), 
    Request.GetInlineCount());
}
```

in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

You are doing ToString() on an IEnumerable collection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-5.0) where instead a forEach would do for example (or even something like `String.Join(",",query.Select(r => r.SomeField))`